# Computer Name Does Not Show Changed In Command Prompt

Tags: windows-10, computer-name

I am the admin on a laptop running Windows 10 64 bit.  I right clicked the start button selected System, and selected Rename This PC and input a new name for the PC.  The new name is reflected in this method.

However, if I right click the start button select run, and type cmd the name that appers to the left of the `>` is UserName.OldPCName

Why did the name not change here, and how do I get it to change here?

Comment: Did you do a reboot ? What name does it show after rebooting?

Comment: @SolarMike - yes have rebooted multiple times, no change.

Comment: Is there another place that the real name is stored : far down in the system settings or control panel : sorry I don’t have  a definitive answer, Someone rlse will though.

Comment: what does `hostname` print when run in cmd.exe? if you hit Win + Pause|Break, is the name displayed the old name? if so change it via the Change Settings link there.

Comment: hostname and win + pause|break print the new computer name.  Upon further examination it appears that what I am seeing is the actual user name.oldPcName -> I only have one user account setup on the PC and it is Administrator.  The name shows Administrator.OldName -> how can I change it to just read Administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because that the Administrator.OldName is your profile name. Here oldName is not your machine name. So when you change your machine name, it cannot re-map there.

The only way is change your user profile name.

1. Open the Local Users and Groups area of the Management Console
2. Double click the account and go to the Profile tab.
3. Enter the profile path and home folder (local path) as "C:\Users\USERNAME\"
4. Copy the contents of "C:\Users\USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME\" and delete "C:\Users\USERNAME\"
5. Recreate the folder "C:\Users\USERNAME\" and paste the contents of "C:\Users\USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME\" into it.
6. Delete "C:\Users\USERNAME.COMPUTERNAME\"
7. restart the computer to check the result.

Comment: +1. The key point, here, is that it's your profile name and not the hostname.